How to interpret annotation data?
I am new to datasets. I have got an annotations train.json for MR image data like this -

I want to train a Yolo-V8 model using this MR data images extracted from dicom raw data and annotations for detection and localization. But I am not able to make any head from this bbox description. I am used to seeing "bbox":[x,y,width,height] type of description.
The link to the dataset is THIS. I have uploaded the complete test.json, train.json, val.json here. please help.

The format description can be found on file DATASET.md at the github repo you linked:

The bounding box (bbox) format is [top left X position, top left Y position, top left Z position, deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ]. NOTE: X corresponds to row (SI), Y to column (AP), and Z (RL/LR) to depth.


Thank you so much and apologies, I should have read the documentation properly
